# Does MATLAB R2022a support gfortran 8.x on Linux (as specified by the documentation)?

Tags: linux, matlab, fortran, gfortran, mex

According to the [official documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html), MATLAB R2022a supports gfortan8.x as the Fortran compiler for MEX on Linux.

However, MATLAB R2022a with gfortran 8.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 fails to run the following code.

```
mex('-setup', '-v', 'FORTRAN'); 
mex('-v', fullfile(matlabroot, 'extern', 'examples', 'refbook', 'timestwo.F'));
```

The error message is as follows.

```
Error using mex
gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fallow-argument-mismatch’; did you mean
‘-Wno-argument-mismatch’?
```

The problem is reproduced on [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/equipez/test_matlab/actions/runs/2002389041). Nevertheless, gfortran 10 and 11 succeed, even though they are not supported officially.

Those who have MATLAB R2022a installed on Ubuntu may have a try on your side. Thank you very much!

A bug report has been submitted to MathWorks, but no real response is received. It is a bit surprising to me how MathWorks handles this kind of bug (or documentation error).

I have posted the question on [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1674509-bug-in-matlab-r2022a-mex-does-not-support-gfortran-8-x-as-specified-in-the-official-documentation), but it seems that not many people are using MATLAB R2022a on Linux (yet).

---

Update: **Why does the error occur?**

According to the documentations of [`gfortran 10.1.0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gfortran/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) and [`gfortran 9.4.0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.4.0/gfortran/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary), the `-fallow-argument-mismatch` flag was first introduced to gfortran in `10.1.0`. Therefore, there is no hope that `gfortran 8.x` could recognize it.

Below are the MEX configuration files of MATLAB Version 9.12.0.1896817 (R2022a, Operating System: Linux 4.14.215-0414215-generic). As we can see, `gfortran6.xml` specifies `-fallow-argument-mismatch` as a compilation option. That is why `gfortran 8.x` cannot work with it.

BTW, another question: **What is the relation and difference between `gfortran6.xml` and `gfortran.xml`? Which one defines the compilation options when `MEX` is invoked?** In my investigation, it seems that `gfortran6.xml` is playing the role, although the name of this file is a bit confusing --- I thought it was the configration for `gfortran 6` or below.

1. `gfortran6.xml` located at `fullfile(matlabroot,'bin', 'glnxa64', 'mexopts', 'gfortran6.xml')`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config
    Name="gfortran"
    ShortName="gfortran"
    Manufacturer="GNU"
    Version="$GFORTRAN_VERSION"
    Language="FORTRAN"
    Priority="A"
    Location="$GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR" >
    <Details
        CompilerExecutable="$FC"
        CompilerDefines="$DEFINES"
        CompilerFlags="$FFLAGS"
        OptimizationFlags="$FOPTIMFLAGS"
        DebugFlags="$FDEBUGFLAGS"
        IncludeFlags="$INCLUDE"
        LinkerLibraries="$LINKLIBS"
        LinkerOptimizationFlags="$LDOPTIMFLAGS"
        LinkerDebugFlags="$LDDEBUGFLAGS"

        CompilerDefineFormatter="-D%s"
        LinkerLibrarySwitchFormatter="-l%s"
        LinkerPathFormatter="-L%s"
    />
    <vars
        CMDLINE1="$FC -c $DEFINES $INCLUDE $FFLAGS $OPTIM $SRC -o $OBJ"
        CMDLINE2="$LDF $LDFLAGS $LDTYPE $LINKOPTIM $LINKEXPORTVER $OBJS $FLIBS $LINKLIBS -o $EXE"

        FC="$GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR/gfortran"
        DEFINES=""
        FFLAGS="-fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fallow-argument-mismatch"
        INCLUDE="-I&quot;$MATLABROOT/extern/include&quot; -I&quot;$MATLABROOT/simulink/include&quot;"
        FOPTIMFLAGS="-O2"
        FDEBUGFLAGS="-g"

        LDF="$FC"
        LDFLAGS="-pthread"
        LDTYPE="-shared"
        LINKEXPORT="-Wl,--version-script,$MATLABROOT/extern/lib/$ARCH/fexport.map"
        LINKEXPORTVER="-Wl,--version-script,$MATLABROOT/extern/lib/$ARCH/fortran_exportsmexfileversion.map"
        MWCPPLIB="&quot;$MATLABROOT/sys/os/$ARCH/orig/libstdc++.so.6&quot;"
        LINKLIBS="-Wl,-rpath-link,$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH  -L&quot;$MATLABROOT/sys/os/$ARCH/orig&quot; -L&quot;$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH&quot; $MWCPPLIB -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -L&quot;$GFORTRAN_LIBDIR&quot; -lgfortran"
        LDOPTIMFLAGS="-O"
        LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
        MW_GLIBC_SHIM="$MW_GLIBC_SHIM"

        OBJEXT=".o"
        LDEXT=".mexa64"

        SETENV="FC=&quot;$FC&quot;
                FFLAGS=&quot;$FFLAGS $DEFINES&quot;
                FOPTIMFLAGS=&quot;$FOPTIMFLAGS&quot;
                FDEBUGFLAGS=&quot;$FDEBUGFLAGS&quot;
                LD=&quot;$FC&quot;
                LDFLAGS=&quot;$LDFLAGS $LDTYPE $LINKLIBS $LINKEXPORT&quot;
                LDDEBUGFLAGS=&quot;$LDDEBUGFLAGS&quot;">

        </vars>

    <!---Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error $LDFEXPORT-->
    <client>
        <engine
            LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS $MW_GLIBC_SHIM -leng"
            LINKEXPORT=""
            LINKEXPORTVER=""
            LDEXT=""
            LDTYPE=""
        />
    </client>
    <locationFinder>
        <GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <dirExists name="$$"/>
            </and>
        </GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR>
        <GFORTRAN_LIBDIR>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <cmdReturns name="gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.so" />
                <dirExists name="$$" />
            </and>
        </GFORTRAN_LIBDIR>
        <GFORTRAN_VERSION>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <cmdReturns name="gfortran -dumpversion | awk -F '.' '$1>=6' " />
            </and>
        </GFORTRAN_VERSION>
    </locationFinder>
</config>
```

2. `gfortran.xml` located at `fullfile(matlabroot,'bin', 'glnxa64', 'mexopts', 'gfortran.xml')`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config
    Name="gfortran6-"
    ShortName="gfortran6-"
    Manufacturer="GNU"
    Version="$GFORTRAN_VERSION"
    Language="FORTRAN"
    Priority="B"
    Location="$GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR" >
    <Details
        CompilerExecutable="$FC"
        CompilerDefines="$DEFINES"
        CompilerFlags="$FFLAGS"
        OptimizationFlags="$FOPTIMFLAGS"
        DebugFlags="$FDEBUGFLAGS"
        IncludeFlags="$INCLUDE"
        LinkerLibraries="$LINKLIBS"
        LinkerOptimizationFlags="$LDOPTIMFLAGS"
        LinkerDebugFlags="$LDDEBUGFLAGS"

        CompilerDefineFormatter="-D%s"
        LinkerLibrarySwitchFormatter="-l%s"
        LinkerPathFormatter="-L%s"
    />
    <vars
        CMDLINE1="$FC -c $DEFINES $INCLUDE $FFLAGS $OPTIM $SRC -o $OBJ"
        CMDLINE2="$LDF $LDFLAGS $LDTYPE $LINKOPTIM $LINKEXPORTVER $OBJS $FLIBS $LINKLIBS -o $EXE"

        FC="$GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR/gfortran"
        DEFINES=""
        FFLAGS="-fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
        INCLUDE="-I&quot;$MATLABROOT/extern/include&quot; -I&quot;$MATLABROOT/simulink/include&quot;"
        FOPTIMFLAGS="-O2"
        FDEBUGFLAGS="-g"

        LDF="$FC"
        LDFLAGS="-pthread"
        LDTYPE="-shared"
        LINKEXPORT="-Wl,--version-script,$MATLABROOT/extern/lib/$ARCH/fexport.map"
        LINKEXPORTVER="-Wl,--version-script,$MATLABROOT/extern/lib/$ARCH/fortran_exportsmexfileversion.map"
        MWCPPLIB="&quot;$MATLABROOT/sys/os/$ARCH/orig/libstdc++.so.6&quot;"
        LINKLIBS="-Wl,-rpath-link,$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH -L&quot;$MATLABROOT/sys/os/$ARCH/orig&quot; -L&quot;$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH&quot; $MWCPPLIB -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -L&quot;$GFORTRAN_LIBDIR&quot; -lgfortran -L&quot;$GFORTRANBEGIN_LIBDIR&quot; -lgfortranbegin"
        LDOPTIMFLAGS="-O"
        LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
        MW_GLIBC_SHIM="$MW_GLIBC_SHIM"

        OBJEXT=".o"
        LDEXT=".mexa64"

        SETENV="FC=&quot;$FC&quot;
                FFLAGS=&quot;$FFLAGS $DEFINES&quot;
                FOPTIMFLAGS=&quot;$FOPTIMFLAGS&quot;
                FDEBUGFLAGS=&quot;$FDEBUGFLAGS&quot;
                LD=&quot;$FC&quot;
                LDFLAGS=&quot;$LDFLAGS $LDTYPE $LINKLIBS $LINKEXPORT&quot;
                LDDEBUGFLAGS=&quot;$LDDEBUGFLAGS&quot;">

        </vars>

    <!---Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error $LDFEXPORT-->
    <client>
        <engine
            LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS $MW_GLIBC_SHIM -leng"
            LINKEXPORT=""
            LINKEXPORTVER=""
            LDEXT=""
            LDTYPE=""
        />
    </client>
    <locationFinder>
        <GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <dirExists name="$$"/>
            </and>
        </GFORTRAN_INSTALLDIR>
        <GFORTRAN_LIBDIR>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <cmdReturns name="gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.so" />
                <dirExists name="$$" />
            </and>
        </GFORTRAN_LIBDIR>
        <GFORTRANBEGIN_LIBDIR>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <cmdReturns name="gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortranbegin.a" />
                <dirExists name="$$" />
            </and>
        </GFORTRANBEGIN_LIBDIR>
        <GFORTRAN_VERSION>
            <and>
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="which gfortran" />
                    <fileExists name="/usr/local/bin/gfortran" />
                </or>
                <cmdReturns name="gfortran -dumpversion" />
            </and>
        </GFORTRAN_VERSION>
    </locationFinder>
</config>
```

Comment: What kind of answer would you expect? It seems you dissected the problem in high detail yourself. Only Mathworks can tell what they officially support. You can only make workarounds in the config file and you found it yourself. Perhaps the second point is a real answerable question (meaning of the A/B priorities), but hardly the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did not find the reason for the error until some time after I posed the question. When I found it, I had two choices: delete the question, or make an update about what I found in order to help others who may run into the same problem. I chose the second. Thanks. BTW, my update does include another question, in case someone here can answer it.